# UIView - allocate vs hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a custom view on my ViewController. I want to remove it when I tap on the screen. It contains image and text.

What is the best way to do this?

I know 2 ways:

1. use `hidden` on tap on the screen throughout `touchesBegan:` and allocate it once.
2. use `removeFromSuperview` and allocate it every time.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking? Can you please elaborate the situation a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on requirement :

1. If on an average, user will tap more times again and again, you should got for hidden approach
2. But if user has to tap a few times, better to go with second approach

Comment: *Why* is one better than the other, in your opinion?

Comment: Better is to go for second approach...as it is seen that on an average, its performance will be better

Comment: You can also do it nil....to dealloc it

Comment: -1 for making assertions without backing them up. Even your comment after my question doesn't explain your thinking. Are you saying that the user might actually notice the time it takes to create a view? And if we accept that hiding the view is better (for performance reasons, or whatever) then why is it *better* to remove the view and create a new one if the user will only tap it a few times. If it's better to use one approach if the user will tap 50 times, why is the other better if the user will tap 5 times? Please **explain** your reasoning on this. As it stands, this answer is not useful.

Comment: My reasoning is quite simple : I am not saying that user has to decide alloc and de-alloc time, if view is need to be displayed again and again, use 1st approach..if user needs view again and like in a game, he can go for second approach. hope you get it now..pleas upvote if you understood now. what I am trying to say

Answer (score 1):

Removing a view from it's superview doesn't necessarily mean that the view will be deallocated. If you keep a strong reference to the view you can add it and remove it as a superview without it being deallocated.